# adding multiple entry in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Below code works adding single single entry i want to store multiple parent_id and user_id

```
public function test($p_id, $pl_id)
    {
        $CheckRelationship = UsersRelationship::where('parent_user_id',  $p_id )->where('child_user_id', $pl_id )->first();

        if( $CheckRelationship )
        {
            return Response::json( [
            'ok'=> false,
            'message'=> 'The profiles are currently linked '
            ] ,422);
        }

        $user = User::find( $pl_id );
        $user->p_id = $p_id;
        $user->updated_by = $p_id;
        //$user->status = 1;
        $user->save();

        $UsersRelationship = new UsersRelationship;
        $UsersRelationship->parent_user_id = $parent_id;
        $UsersRelationship->child_user_id = $player_id;


        $UsersRelationship->save();



        return Response::json( [
        'ok'=> true,
        'message'=> 'Linked',
        ] ,200);
    }
```

I want to pass multiple value

```
$UsersRelationship = new UsersRelationship;
        $UsersRelationship->parent_user_id = $parent_id; //single value passing
        $UsersRelationship->child_user_id = $player_id; //single value passing


            $UsersRelationship->save();

  foreach($UsersRelationship as $k=>$values){
            $UsersRelationship['parent_user_id'] = $values;
            $UsersRelationship['child_user_id'] = $values;
             $UsersRelationship->save();

  }
```

doesn't work for me please suggest where i am mistaking early reply highly appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: foreach($UsersRelationship as $key=>$values){
   $multiRelationship[parent_user_id] = $values;
   $multiRelationship[child_user_id] = $values;
  }

$multiRelationship->save();
doesn't work

Comment: insert `->save()` inside foreach

Comment: $multiRelationship->save();

if i entering says Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Comment: foreach($UsersRelationship as $key=>$values){
   $multiRelationship['parent_user_id'] = $values;
   $multiRelationship['child_user_id'] = $values;
   $UsersRelationship->save();
  }
says Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Comment: url hitting http://localhost:9000/v1/xyz/4444/myplayer/12693,16054/multiple

want to store 12693,16054 values

Comment: Cant get your question.

Comment: take a look again i edited

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in URLs will work only for a singular user relationship. If you wish to pass multiple relationships, JSON is your friend.

**JSON Sample:**

```
[
    {
    'parent_user_id': 1,
    'child_user_id': 2,
    },
    {
    'parent_user_id': 2,
    'child_user_id': 2,
    }    
]
```

**PHP controller function:**

```
public function test(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    //Pass your information through a GET parameter or POST it through a form
    // 'user_relationship' is the name of the field, expecting data in JSON format
    $user_relationships = json_decode($request->get('user_relationship'));

    //array to store all relationships that were not linked
    $relationshipsNotLinked= [];

    //Loop through each relationship, attach where possible
    foreach($user_relationships as $user_relationship_row) {
        $CheckRelationship = UsersRelationship::where('parent_user_id',  $user_relationship_row['parent_user_id'] )->where('child_user_id', $user_relationship_row['child_user_id'] )->first();

        //If exists, we don't save.
        if( $CheckRelationship ) {
            $relationshipsNotLinked[] =  $user_relationship_row['child_user_id'];
        } else {
            //Else we link relationship

            //Not sure what the links below does..
            //users cannot have `p_id` attribute, given that they may have multiple parents. Same goes for 'updated_by' attribute
            $user = User::find( $user_relationship_row['parent_user_id'] );
            $user->updated_by = $user_relationship_row['parent_user_id'];
            //$user->status = 1;
            $user->save();

            //Save relationship
            $UsersRelationship = new UsersRelationship();
            $UsersRelationship->parent_user_id = $user_relationship_row['parent_user_id'];
            $UsersRelationship->child_user_id = $user_relationship_row['child_user_id'];
            $UsersRelationship->save();


        }

    }


    if(count($relationshipsNotlinked)) {
        //Some relationships were not linked, we display an error message
        return Response::json( [
        'ok'=> false,
        'message'=> 'The following profiles are already linked: '.implode(',',relationshipsNotLinked),
        ] ,422);    
    } else {
        //Display success message
        return Response::json( [
        'ok'=> true,
        'message'=> 'Linked',
        ] ,200);     
    }

}
```

Comment: in that you function you pass Illuminate\Http\Request, string can i pass $parent_id, $player_id values because i m getting error in url string given

also my hitting url is localhost:9000/v1/xyz/4444/myplayer/12693,16054/multiple

Array[12693,16054] getting from the js

Comment: just changes in your code public function multiplelinkPlayerWithFamily($parent_id, $player_id)
 {
  
  $user_relationships = ''; 
  $user_relationships .= json_decode($parent_id->get('user_relationship'));
  $user_relationships .= json_decode($player_id->get('user_relationship'));

got error (Call to a member function get() on a non-object)

Comment: You cannot use the url `localhost:9000/v1/xyz/4444/myplayer/12693,16054/multiple Array[12693,16054]`. Instead, create an ajax (POST or GET) function which sends the data in JSON format with the parameter `user_relationship`. Add your current JS in your question, and i'll modify it accordingly.

Comment: $http.post("v1/xyz/"+$scope.user.user_id+"/multiple", {"player_id":$scope.selection})
      .success(function (response){
//code
}

Comment: Argument 1 passed to ApiUserController::test() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given error showing

Comment: Js should be: `$http.post("v1/xyz/multiple", [{"parent_user_id":$scope.selection,"child_user_id":$scope.user.user_id}]) .success(function (response){ //code }` Assuming that your laravel routes are configured properly.

Comment: Yes it is but your provide php controller function throw me error Argument 1 passed to ApiUserController::test() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given

Comment: my model is like
class UsersRelationship extends Eloquent  
{


 protected $table = 'users_relationships';

 public $primaryKey = 'id';

 protected $hidden = array();

 protected $guarded = array();

 protected $fillable = array();